# Additional visa needed to travel to Belarus with Russian visa for EU citizen?

Tags: visas, russia, eu-citizens, belarus

I am a German citizen currently living in Russia with a Russian study visa. I am planning on driving to Minsk with a car and from there to Poland. Since I already have a visa for Russia, is a special visa required for Belarus? I am aware of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/do-i-need-a-visa-to-visit-belarus-if-i-have-a-russian-visa) but my question differs in the respect that I am not an US, but a EU citizen and that I am not entering Belarus by plane or train.

Comment: While your citizenship and the mode of travel may be different, I expect that the answer is the same.

Comment: Yes, you still have to have a valid visa, as Belarus doesn't have non-visa agreement with both US and EU. And you probably can't travel to Minsk by a car.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but this is indeed the same question. Belarusian visa and Russian visa are quite distinct. And it doesn’t matter if you enter by plane, train, car or foot.

Comment: The above speakers are right: you have seamlessly use the duplicate question above, as Belarus makes **no distinction** between EU and US foreigners. You definitely need Belarusian visa.

Comment: The only addition can be put here is that if you are planning to stay in Belarus for less than 24h, you will be treated as transit passenger and are not required a visa. But **only** if you make a change on international air flight in MInsk airport. Ground vehicles are excluded from this rule.

Comment: Also some points about crossing BY-RU border may interest you [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/80619/42757)